# angularjs ngroute not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i am new in angularjs i have a index page with some data with anchor tag   when user click in a particular anchor tag page redirect to list page and show data but ngRoute not working  and also the not getting the query string value. Where i wrong
this is my index page

```
<div class="all_cat" ng-repeat="state in statelist">
    <h2>{{state.Statename}}</h2>
    <div class="cat-col-4" ng-repeat="citylist in state.city">
        <ul>
            <li><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><a href="/Job/JobList/{{citylist.ID}}">{{citylist.cityname}} </a>({{citylist.jobcount}})</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and this is my js

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'angularTrix', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider
        .when('/JobList:ID', {
            templateUrl: 'job/JobList.cshtml',
            controller: 'joblist'
        })

});


app.controller('joblist', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    debugger;
    $scope.message = 'Clicked person name from home page should be display here';
    $scope.person = $routeParams.ID;
});
```

i am not under stand where i do wrong

Comment: You might want `/JobList/:ID` instead of `/JobList:ID`

Comment: Same problem  $routeParams.ID is undefined

Comment: Have you tried `$route.current.params` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Ass braja lal Mahanty tell you might want /JobList/:ID instead of /JobList:ID.
So you have to set state as:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/JobList/:ID', {
        templateUrl: 'job/JobList.cshtml',
         controller: 'joblist'
    })
});
```